# Content, starts and stops of ChunkedArray - built from lazyarray

Tags: python, uproot, awkward-array

I have some code that works fine for `JaggedArrays` extracting `content`, `starts`, `stops`, but I would like to run the same code on some `ChunkedArrays`, obtained from `lazyarrays` from `uproot`.
Unfortunately, I obtained the following error:

```
~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awkward/array/base.py in __getattr__(self, where)
    254                     raise AttributeError("while trying to get column {0}, an exception occurred:\n{1}: {2}".format(repr(where), type(err), str(err)))
    255             else:
--> 256                 raise AttributeError("no column named {0}".format(repr(where)))
    257 
    258     def __dir__(self):

AttributeError: no column named 'starts'
```

Is there any way to make this working?

Answer (score 1):

It's gradually becoming clear that properties like `starts`, `stops`, and `content` should not be public—they should be treated as internals. They're part of what makes a `JaggedArray` work, but not properties of any jagged data (any arrays whose `type` is `[0, N) -> [0, inf) -> X` for some array length `N` and inner type `X`).

You would like to not care that your jagged data is a `ChunkedArray`, and for many operations, like `flatten()` and `counts`, you don't care: they work equally well on a `ChunkedArray` as a `JaggedArray`. But `starts`, `stops`, and `content` won't ever be like that: they don't have meaning beyond the specific implementation of a `JaggedArray`.

Consider, for instance, this `ChunkedArray`:

```py
>>> array = awkward.ChunkedArray([awkward.fromiter([[1, 2, 3], [], [4, 5]]),
...                               awkward.fromiter([[100], [200, 300]])])
>>> array
<ChunkedArray [[1 2 3] [] [4 5] [100] [200 300]] at 0x796a969db6a0>
```

We can get at the `starts` and `stops` of each `chunk`, but it's probably not what you want:

```py
>>> [x.starts for x in array.chunks]
[array([0, 3, 3]), array([0, 1])]
>>> [x.stops for x in array.chunks]
[array([3, 3, 5]), array([1, 3])]
```

(In your case, you have lazy arrays, which are `ChunkedArray` of `VirtualArray`, so you would have to do `x.array.starts` instead of `x.starts`, to unpack the `VirtualArray`. This is another property that should probably be internal, for the same reasons.)

Notice that the `starts` of the second `chunk` starts over at `0`? That's because the indexes are relative to your current `chunk` (so that `chunks` can be processed in parallel). If you were using `starts` as part of a data analysis, that would be an important correction. (You could add `stops[-1] if len(stops) > 0 else 0` of the previous `chunk` to the current `chunk` to make the numbers global.)

A perhaps better alternative is to construct meaningful offsets from `counts`. The `ChunkedArray` has a functioning `counts`:

```py
>>> array.counts
array([3, 0, 2, 1, 2])
```

The `counts` is the length of each subarray in the jagged data, which is a derivative of the `offsets`, which is `starts` and `stops` overlapped:

```py
>>> offsets = numpy.empty(len(array) + 1, dtype=int)
>>> offsets[0] = 0
>>> numpy.cumsum(array.counts, out=offsets[1:])
array([3, 3, 5, 6, 8])
>>> offsets
array([0, 3, 3, 5, 6, 8])
>>> starts, stops = offsets[:-1], offsets[1:]
>>> starts
array([0, 3, 3, 5, 6])
>>> stops
array([3, 3, 5, 6, 8])
```

You can use these as `starts` and `stops`, but only if you have some kind of "content" for which the `starts` and `stops` are completely contiguous. That's not guaranteed for a `JaggedArray`'s `content`, but `flatten()` will do that for you:

```py
>>> content = array.flatten()
>>> content
<ChunkedArray [1 2 3 ... 100 200 300] at 0x796aa12b1940>
```

Now, for instance, the subarray at index `3` is

```py
>>> content[starts[3]:stops[3]]
<ChunkedArray [100] at 0x796a96a3b978>
```

This is precisely why Awkward 0's `ChunkedArray`, `JaggedArray`, etc. are going to become internal "for experts only" classes in [Awkward 1](https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward-1.0#readme). The user interface in Awkward 1 will have a single `awkward.Array` class with a `type` to know if it's jagged or not. Whether it's made out of chunks or something else will be an implementation detail.

Comment: This makes perfect sense.
To be more precise, at the moment, I need `starts`, `stops`, and `content` because I need to apply operations that are not `numpy ufunc`. For this reason, I extract the content of the array, apply my operation, and then build back the resulting array using:
```
awkward.JaggedArray(content=out,
                                   starts=starts,
                                   stops=stops)
```
Which solution do you suggest for this specific situation?

Comment: For that specific situation, you can use the `starts`, `stops`, and `content` that I derived above. The result of that will be a `JaggedArray` whose `content` is a `ChunkedArray`, which _should_ work. I hope it doesn't give you any trouble. If you need to make the `ChunkedArray` non-chunked (to pass it through a non-ufunc, for instance), concatenate the chunks: `np.concatenate(content.chunks)` or `np.concatenate([x.array for x in content.chunks])`.